# Create user with specific SID in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sid

I need to create a user on my test server that has the same SID as the same user on the live server. This is due to the fact that we frequently copy databases from the live server to the test server to get fresh data, when this is done the user I have on the test server has no access to the copied databases since the user has a different SID than on the live server.

I think I already have the solution, but I'm a bit afraid of just running it straight up. If I seriously mess up then I'll be in trouble. Sure, not as much trouble as if I had run it on the live server, but still. It's not optimal to screw up the test server either.

```
USE master
GO

DROP LOGIN myuser
GO

CREATE LOGIN [myuser] 
     WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword',
     SID = 0xEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE40EE,
     DEFAULT_DATABASE = [MYDB],
     DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english],
     CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,
     CHECK_POLICY = ON
GO

ALTER LOGIN [myuser] ENABLE
GO

USE MYDB
GO

DROP USER myuser
GO

CREATE USER myuser FOR LOGIN myuser
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'myuser'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'myuser'
```

Is this correct??

Comment: Looks good. Maybe some actions are unnecessary, for example, alter login enable -- the login created is enabled by default. And instead of drop/create the user you can use ALTER USER WITH LOGIN

Comment: Obviously, if you use ALTER USER WITH LOGIN you should not reassign role membership and all the permissions will be preserved. The command will just update user's sid

Comment: Alternatively, you could use reuse the "username" as "sid" in all databases. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56771220/how-to-calculate-the-sid-for-new-logins for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to do that. All you need to do is synchronize the SIDs that associate the user with the login.  And what happens if the SID you are attempting to use exists in your instance?

Much easier is to use the script Erland posted [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a4e7c8f5-d9e7-487b-b141-ef4b15ad4f58/sync-users-and-logins?forum=sqlsecurity)