# How to calculate the SID for new logins?

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I want to create a number of database users on two sql server instances. To be able to easily copy databases from one instance to another, I want the SIDs to be consistent.

My idea was to use predictable SIDs, to minimize maintenance pain. I a dreaming about something like this:

```
CREATE LOGIN newuser1 WITH PASSWORD = '...', SID = CAST('newuser1' AS BINARY(16))

-- or alternatively:
CREATE LOGIN newuser1 WITH PASSWORD = '...', SID = HASHBYTES('newuser1')
```

Calculating values for the SID, however, seems not to be supported by the `CREATE LOGIN` command:

```
Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 1
Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von "SID". -- Wrong syntax near "SID"
```

How can I use a calculated value for `SID`?

Comment: `EXEC` and dynamic SQL are your friends for any command that doesn't allow parameterization (well, within reason of course...).

Comment: If you want to have the same SID across multiple instances, why not create one on the first instance (Development?) get the SID's for those, and then alter your `CREATE` statement to include it for the remainder of the instances? The reason for the error, by the way, is because you need to provide a string literal for the value of `SID`, not an expression.

Comment: @Larnu Creating a user, selectings its SID and then writing another sql based on that for the second database seems more complicated to me then running the same, predictable script on both databases.

Comment: @jeroen-mostert Using dynamic SQL works (I posted an answer). Thanks for the tip. Still I hope, that someone finds a shorter/easier answer...

Answer (score 2):

This can be accomplished by assembling the sql statement in a variable and the executing it with `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQL = 'CREATE LOGIN newuser1 WITH PASSWORD = ''...'', SID = 0x'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), CAST('newuser1' AS binary(16)), 2)
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Alternatively, if you want to reuse this approach, you can use create a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE create_user_with_predictable_sid
    @UserName varchar(256),
    @Password varchar(256)
AS
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000) = 'CREATE LOGIN '+@UserName+' WITH PASSWORD = '''+@Password+''', SID = 0x'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), CAST(@UserName AS binary(16)), 2)
PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
GO  

GO

create_user_with_predictable_sid 'newuser1', '...'
GO

DROP PROCEDURE create_user_with_predictable_sid
```

Comment: I strongly suggest quoting your objects properly here; otherwise this is an injection issue. Also you should really be using `sysname` here. A username can only be a maximum of 128 characters, and *does* allow non-Ascii characters.